# Padding/margin on the left side of my activity/actionbar - dont know where it comes from, cannot remove it

Tags: android

There is some padding or margin to the left of my appbar/toolbar and my activity. I don't know where it comes from and I don't know how to remove it.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.my.example"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|locale|layoutDirection|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

        </activity>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/weekendDayBackgroundColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>
    <!--<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>-->

    <!--<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>-->

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/lightBlue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="loader_border_width">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="loader_size">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvAppHeaderTextSize">42sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="etPasswordBottomMargin">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="bLoginSubmitTopMargin">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

my_activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLegend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />

                <!--<ImageButton-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/bBack"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
                    <!--android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"-->
                    <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->
                    <!--android:src="@mipmap/arrow_left"/>-->
            </FrameLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLegend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Testing on Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

to your toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLegend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```